# How do I get a class to run first in a Win Forms App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, startup, program-entry-point

I need to run a class called StartUp.cs when the application starts.  I want the class to assign values to a different class called MyAppSettings.cs.  Now when the Form frmMainConsole loads I want it to read the values from Settings because it effect controls on the Form frmMainConsole.  I have tried several ways and realize I need help with this.

Comment: I think you need to post your code so we can get an idea of what you've tried thus far. Probably easier to point you to a solution that way.

Comment: Yeah, and post the code you've tried. Also. make the question clearer , I cannot understand

Comment: Here is the Form load Methodprivate void frmMainConsole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
            CreateGroupBox();
            //Set Initial Settings
            MyAppSetting MyAppSetting = new ChessStrategyGame.MyAppSetting();
            movesToolStripMenuItem.Checked = MyAppSetting.ShowMoves;
            
        }

Comment: You have a `StartUp.cs` to assign some values to `MyAppSettings.cs`? And where is that `StartUp.cs` getting those values from?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `Program.cs`, you'll see something like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

You can simply add your StartUp.cs calls above `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state - post some code you've tried, however, see if the following is what you need

```
public class InitialiseSettings
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        //Code to run here
    }

    public InitialiseSettings()
    {

    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Instantiate an object here of the class or call a static function of that class etc etc
        InitialiseSettings settings = new InitialiseSettings();
        InitialiseSettings.Initialise();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Or you could do it here - before the form is displayed
    }
}
```

Or you could invoke your Class before the form is even instantiated (Program.cs)

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Invoke class here
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While modifying Program.cs file works, you may also want to add a static void `Main()` method to your `StartUp` class and make that your starting point in your project. This will give you ultimate control over how your application starts.

You can set the Startup object in the Application page of the Project Designer. Note that it also means you won't be able to use the default winform application framework though. But if you seek more control over your app settings then this may be for the best anyway.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17k74w0c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong part of the code is

```
//Set Initial Settings 
MyAppSetting MyAppSetting = new ChessStrategyGame.MyAppSetting();
```

This way you end up with creating a new object each time .

### Solution :

If you make your settings class "MyAppSettings.cs" a static one , it would help you. 
Generally settings classes created as static so that you set the values once and can access the properties / values through out the application .

e.g.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // create object of startup class and call initialize method
    StartUp newStartUp = new StartUp();
    newStartup.Initialize();

    Application.Run(new Form1());
}


StartUp.cs
----------
public class StartUp
{

    public void Initialize()
    {
        MyAppSettings.ShowMoves = true;    
    }

}

MyAppSettings.cs
----------------
public static MyAppSettings
{
    public static bool ShowMoves {get; set;}
}

Form1.cs
--------
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateGroupBox();

    //Set Initial Settings 
    movesToolStripMenuItem.Checked = MyAppSetting.ShowMoves;
}
```